# Installing lpsolve to work with python in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, installation, lpsolve

Read other questions; unfortunately they were not relevant.

Using this tutorial:
http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/Python.htm

Found this file:
lp_solve_5.5.2.0_exe_ux32

That contains these files:

1. libbfp_etaPFI.so
2. libbfp_GLPK.so
3. libbfp_LUSOL.so
4. libxli_CPLEX.so
5. libxli_DIMACS.so
6. libxli_LINDO.so
7. libxli_MathProg.so
8. libxli_XPRESS.so
9. libxli_ZIMPL.so
10. lp_solve

The tutorial says the need file is:
lpsolve55.so

How do you get lpsolve working with Python in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need this file:
`lp_solve_5.5.2.0_Python2.5_exe_ux64.tar.gz`

Inside it you will find: `liblpsolve55.so`

You need to put that file in a place accessible to the python path. Had problems doing that so it's in the project's folder.

You also need this file: 
`lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_ux64.tar.gz`

Inside it you will find:
`liblpsolve55.so`

This file needs to go to `/lib/usr`

Answer (score 1):

This is for installing lpsolve55 in Python, anaconda in ubuntu distribution, [translated from the blogpost (which is in Chinese)](http://blog.hoamon.info/2007/10/lpsolve.html)

1. go download at sourceforge

   > lp_solve_5.5.0.20_dev.tar.gz - where you would find *liblpsolve55.so* and some other files
   >   lp_solve_5.5.0.20_Python_source.tar.gz - where you would find lpsolve55.so and setup.py
2. make sure you have install python-dev (if not, type sudo apt-get install python-dev at the command line)
3. unzip **lp_solve_5.5.0.20_Python_source.tar.gz** and put the file at **anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/**
4. unzip **lp_solve_5.5.0.20_dev.tar.gz** and put "only" the  **liblpsolve55.so** at **anaconda2/lib**, and the rest at **anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lp_solve_5.5**, the directory you get at step 3, in the same layer as extra. [The result would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPGnM.png)
5. Now

   > $ cd anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lp_solve_5.5/extra/Python/
   >   $ python setup.py install
6. Test by **import lpsolve55**